# VFX Workflow - Color Grade

Tags: color, file-format

I am trying to incorporate a few VFX elements in a music video that we did recently. I am an enthusiast with no real VFX experience so I have a few questions that I hope you'll help me with.

1. The final VFX elements will be composited in After Effects. I have been motion tracking on a .mp4 file inside Blender. Is this okay since the compositing will be done inside a different software ? Maybe a .png sequence will be better ?
2. We shot the video on a Red Helium. The log footage that I exported from Davinci Resolve is very flat. Is it advisable that I apply a light grade on the footage before I start working on it inside Blender ? At least convert the log footage to rec709 colour space ?
3. I also have a few problematic shots that I want to hand over to some professionals.   Since I can't decide on the final colour grade yet, will they be okay with the log footage ? They will be painting out some shadows that have spilled over on to the scene ... What would be the safest approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good solution to use EXR here. EXR saves color in floating point numbers, so you can apply any color grade after. The only one drawback is massive file size.

EXR saves colors in linear color space, so then you use it in a compositing software, you might have to apply something linear to gamma 2.2 or linear to sRGB LUT first.

But in my opinion, you should decide colors first, because you can set up different light schemes depending on mood and color.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I just discovered EXR recently ... I was aware of dpx since we used those on one of our short films a long time back. Even with .dpx I wasn't able to motion track the footage because it was laggy as hell. Do you think I will experience the same with EXR ?

 I see that there's a proxy mode in the motion tracking page but I have never used it before. 

You also mention that I should decide on a colour grade beforehand ... I’ve never approached a project in this manner before. Is this normal?

Comment: I have got no issues in Davinchi Resolve with EXR even with playback. But I have M.2. For the AE, I don't know